# JavaScript eventhandler: problem with execution of handler that got parameters

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I have this problem:

I have defined an event handler which requires parameters on it.

```
var handler = function(p1, p2){
    //some code
}
```

Then I add the event handler to an object inside a function.

```
function foo(p1, p2){
    //Some code
    obj.addEventListener('click', handler(p1, p2), false)
}
```

As you already know the code above is not correct. It wont listen to the event. Instead it will execute the function instantly. Now to fix this I can just erase `handler(p1, p2)` and insert `function(){ handler(p1, p2) }` instead. But the problem is that I have an another function that I want to remove the event listener, which is not possible with the latter solution.

```
function koo(){
    //Some code
    obj.removeEventListener('click', handler, false)
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you doing this only for one element or for several? In which scope do `foo` and `koo` live? How does `koo` know which handler to remove?

Comment: Sorry for late response I'm doing  it for several elements and foo and koo are defined in the global scope, not inside any other function, if I had understood you correctly. And there is several function others than koo, that removes the event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll need to create a closure:

```
var createHandler = function(p1, p2){
    return function (event) {
        //some code that uses p1 and p2
    };
};

var handler;
```

...and now you can assign the handler like so, while still having access to p1 and p2:

```
function foo(p1, p2){
    handler = createHandler(p1, p2);
    //Some code
    obj.addEventListener('click', handler, false);
}

function koo(){
    //Some code
    obj.removeEventListener('click', handler, false);
    handler = null;
}
```

Note that `handler` is now a global variable.

---

**Update**: I just realized that in your case, this could be simplified by merging `createHandler` and `foo` as follows:

```
var handler; // we need this to be accessible both to foo and koo

function foo(p1, p2){
    handler = function(event) {
        // some code that uses p1 and p2
    };
    //Some code
    obj.addEventListener('click', handler, false);
}

function koo(){
    //Some code
    obj.removeEventListener('click', handler, false);
    handler = null;
}
```

Comment: I have tested it now. The problem is that var handler = createHandler(p1, p2); must be defined inside function foo to work. Outside didn't worked. But if it isn't outside I can't remove the event listener, so same problem

Comment: Then put `var handler;` outside the `foo` function (thereby creating a global variable). I’ve updated the answer.

Comment: No problem (and thanks for the rep points ;-)).  BTW, I just realized  it could be simplified a bit, see updated answer.

Comment: @Woho87: Does this work for you? This was the reason for my question: It works fine if you always call `koo` after `foo`. But as soon as you call `foo` twice, you loose the reference to the handler created first and there is no way to remove it then. The code as it stands only supports creation and removal of one handler...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you want to pass arguments there - because it is a callback, and you are never sure what those variables will be.

Can you do...

```
(function() {

   var p1 = 'a',
       p2 = 'b',
       obj = document.getElementById('my-object');

   var handleClick = function(event) {
      // Access to p1 and p2
      // Access to `event` object containing info about the event
   }

   obj.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

   // If you want to remove it
   obj.removeEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

})();
```

May I ask why you want to have arguments on it? Do you intend to call it from a non click triggered way as well?

Comment: Can you pls explain what ´(function(){  //some code }()´ does? I have never seen that before? Also didn't you forgot the ')' at the end?

Comment: You have to put the `var handleClick` assignment before `addEventListener`. Otherwise, `handleClick` will be `undefined`.

Comment: @Woho87: Yes he does and it is an immediate function. `funtion(){...}` is the definition and `()` executes the function immediately. This is used to create a privat scope.

Comment: @Woho87 Thanks, fixed. And what Felix says... :)

Comment: Btw, another option would have been to use a *function definition* , i.e. just `function handleClick(){...}`, then you can put them in any order. But if you use variables, the variable will be undefined until a value is assigned to it in the code.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about hoisting not working when you do function declarations. Thanks for jogging my memory.

Comment: @Alex: When I remove eventListener why do I addEventListener in the last rows? I haven't implemented the code yet, but I remove and add the event listeners in function foo and koo in my real problem. Actually foo takes the parameters p1 and p2 and passes it to the handler. The handler needs to be defined globally. When I think logically your code won't work? Or Have I missunderstood you?

Comment: @Woho87 Sorry, that was my mistake! It indeed should be `removeEventListener()`, and I have changed the code. You may have misunderstood me.

Comment: @Alex: I just don't know where function foo and koo comes in, in your code? p1 and p2 changes all the time too, they are pretty dynamic. And it is function foo who is taking the arguments and passes it to the handler. With your code isn't p1 and p2 more lika variables than parameters?

Comment: @Alex: I don't see the difference between having the (function{})() and not having it at all? If you say it exectues immediatly? would'nt it execute it anyway without (function{})()?

Comment: @Woho87 By having it there, it contains all the inner variables to that scope.

Comment: @Alex: Now I figured out that you have missunderstood me. You think foo and koo only purspose is to remove and addEventListener. They do other functions too and needed to be access outside a private scope, so does the handler

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it just this:

```
function foo(){
    //Some code
    obj.addEventListener('click', handler, false)
}
```

Pass the function instead of calling it.

Comment: To clarifiy: when you set the listener as `handler(p1, p2)` you are calling `handler` with two arguments (`p1` and `p2`) and the the value it returns and assigning that to the event instead of assigning the function `handler` as the listener as you clearly intend.

Comment: That will only pass an `event` argument, won't it (not `p1` or `p2`)? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/nzDEL/)

Comment: what about the parameters? p1 and p2 needs to be passed too, that's the problem